# Is every group realized as the group of units of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given an arbitrary group $ G $, in general does there exist a ring $ R $ with $ R^{\times} \cong G $? Or are there counterexamples of this?

Comment: Good question - See here for an answer - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384422/which-finite-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-ring