# Which finite abelian groups contain the group of units of some integer as a direct summand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, abelian-groups

As clear from the title itself, I want to know if there are any characterizing properties (of say, orders and their prime divisors, on elementary divisors, invariant factors, composition series etc.) which classify the finite abelian groups $G$ for which there exist $n \in \mathbb Z_{> 2}$ and an (abelian) group $H$ such that $G \cong (\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z)^\times \oplus H$. It is clear that this is equivalent to having $G \cong (\mathbb Z / p^k \mathbb Z)^\times \oplus H \cong \mathbb Z / p^{k-1} \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z / (p-1)\mathbb Z\oplus H$ for some prime $p$ and $k \in \mathbb N$ (one direction being tautological and the other being a consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem). Any thoughts/ideas, suggestions, (partial or complete) results in that direction, proofs or references would be really appreciated.

**Edit:** I also just discovered this ([Which finite groups are the group of units of some ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384422/which-finite-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-ring)) post, although that asks which groups are exactly *equal* to the group fo units of some ring. The condition I want is much weaker (at least as far as I can see) and I think it should probably have a much more elementary answer.