# Which groups are the unit group of some integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384422/which-finite-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, I wonder if there is some classification of all the groups which are the unit groups of some integral domain.

Since the question about rings is hard, I assume this is hard too, however perhaps the limitation to integral domains makes the question easier somehow (but if it does I don't see it).

Comment: It's a well known result that finite supgroups of unit groups of domains are cyclic. Furthermore, finite domains are fields, so I think the only finite groups which appear as unit groups of domains are cyclic groups of order $p^n -1$ with $p$ prime.

Comment: There might be infinite domains with finite unit groups which aren't of order $p^n -1$ though.