# Which finite groups of odd order are not isomorphic to the group of units of some ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for some examples of odd order finite groups, that are not isomorphic to the group of units of some ring (ring has identity and is associative)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384422/which-finite-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-ring

Comment: @lhf Thank you for your reply. I saw this post. Answers there focus on classifying groups, that are unit groups of ring. I tried to think of some solutions for my question, based on that classification, but failed and decided to ask here

Comment: I think $C_5$ is an example. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/is-the-group-of-units-of-a-finite-ring-cyclic

Comment: @lhf Could you provide some proof on why C5 satisfies the conditions. Also answer, that you linked addresses only commutative rings or maybe i missed something

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384362/group-of-invertible-elements-of-a-ring-has-never-order-5

Comment: @lhf Thank you!